# How to increase Bluetooth LE transmission speed in Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to increase the transmission speed between a micro-controller with BC118 Bluetooth LE module (**server**) and my Android device. Is there a way to make Android Bluetooth LE onCharacteristicChanged() method being called more frequently? If not, how should I increase the speed of transmission?

The BC118 Bluetooth LE module on server side is set to transparent mode and the baud rate is at 9600. On the Android side, I'm supposed to send a byte array of request (e.g. "PIA\r") to the server and the server is supposed to send back the information required. I'm setting up the onCharacteristicChanged() method to read and print out all received data in log. Here I found the speed of Bluetooth gatt notifying me is slow. I can get around 350 bytes/sec on average. Also it looks like the notification are raised on a constant frequency.

Here is the BluetoothGattCallback I built:

```java
public void connectBluetoothLeDevice(final BleDevice device, final ConnectionCallback cb){
    mBluetoothGatt = device.getDevice().connectGatt(ctx, NO_AUTO_CONNECT, new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){
                gatt.discoverServices();
            } else {
                cb.onFinishConnect(false);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
                setupUuid(device.getUuid());
                setNotification();
                cb.onFinishConnect(true);
            } else {
                cb.onFinishConnect(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            byte[] array = characteristic.getValue();
            //Log.e("msg", byteArrToStr(array));
            addToBuffer(array);
        }
    });
}

private void setNotification(){
    BluetoothGattService service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(service_uuid);
    if(service != null){
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic bluetoothGattCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(characteristic_uuid);
        if(bluetoothGattCharacteristic != null){
            mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(bluetoothGattCharacteristic, true);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = bluetoothGattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(CCCD);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set the BluetoothGatt to high priority:

```java
mBluetoothGatt.requestConnectionPriority(BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

but seems like it didn't increase the speed of receiving.

I was using Bluetooth 2.0 previously and the retrieving speed is about twice to current speed. I'm expecting the same thing for Bluetooth LE.

I'm assuming the cause of the low transmitting speed is:
1. I missed some kind of setup when connecting to BLE service or setting up notification, OR
2. The baud rate of the BC118 Bluetooth Module is not high enough, it should be set to 115200.

Comment: Not sure how baud rate would be relevant for BLE; that's something used for UART. Anyway this question has been asked many times before. See for example https://punchthrough.com/maximizing-ble-throughput-on-ios-and-android/ for an introduction.

Comment: @Emil The BLE module can be set to transparent mode with virtual UART. The baud rate is for that.